# What's the difference between GetFullPath(".") and Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()?

Tags: c#

It might be a trivial question but I'm trying to understand the difference between these two different APIs used in this case. It seems to be that they are identical.

I wrote a quick testing program and looked at the returned value in debug mode, and value returned from these two APIs are identical:

```
var result = Path.GetFullPath(".");               -> ..\source\\repos\\TestingApp\\TestingAppDotNet\\bin\\Debug
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();    -> ..\source\\repos\\TestingApp\\TestingAppDotNet\\bin\\Debug
```

Is this more like a personal preference thing?

Comment: There is an enormous amount of code underneath GetFullPath() to deal with potentially malformed argument values.  Skip all that code with GetCurrentDirectory().  In general, strongly avoid assuming that the current directory is set where you hope it is, it is one of the worst global state variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Igor's response, you can check the .net source code:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,eebef077ff3930e1

Basically `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` does this (simplified):

```
buffer = Win32Native.GetCurrentDirectoryW();
if (buffer.Contains('~'))
    return LongPathHelper.GetLongPathName(buffer);
return buffer.ToString();
```

While `Path.GetFullPath()` does a LOT more, you can check it here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,ecfb67b37299beba

After lots of checks, it basically ends with `LongPathHelper.Normalize(path)`.

So I would just use the first option, as it also communicates better your intentions.

Comment: Why was Igor's answer deleted? :( It basically said you should get the same from both calls.